Could not find com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.0
when i start a project Starting Build   in android studio

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'demo'.


Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.0.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.8.0/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.8.0.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.8.0/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.8.0.pom
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.8.0/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.8.0.pom
- https://jitpack.io/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.8.0/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.8.0.pom
Required by:
project :


Try:

i have configure

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.0'

//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.0'
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.8'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

i find no com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin  in   repository
img

JCenter is sunset for the good, and looks like your plugin is now on the Gradle Plugins portal. To access that, you can edit your repositories block as follows
repositories {
        // Remove jcenter
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal() // Add this
    }



i have find the question : Bintray is shutting down . i should try replacing out Bintray: https://plugins.gradle.org/docs/bintray

Right, hope my answer helped you! If it did please mark it as accepted
